# Testing drawRect with OCMock and GHUnit

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a custom view which is used as the view to an NSStatusItem. I'd like to test that drawRect is called on it after setNeedsDisplay has been called.

```
    CustomView * customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:...];

    id mockView = [OCMockObject partialMockForClass:customView];
    [[mockView expect] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [[mockView expect] drawRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 150, 22)];

    [customView setString:@"SomeString"]; // This causes the drawRect message to be sent to customView

    [mockView verify];`
```

Any help most appreciated.

The error I get is "Expected method not invoked: drawRect"

I'm also using GHUnit and have overriden the shouldRunOnMainThread to return YES.

Answer (score 0):

The `drawRect:` selector would be called from a ViewController.  In your test code above you have created the view but you didn't add it to anything, so it isn't being drawn at all, regardless of how the properties in the class behave.

If you created a test View Controller, added your custom view to it, then called the setString selector I would bet that your verify would pass.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I should point out that my app is a desktop app, not an iOS app, if I left that impression, my apologies. If you were referring to the AppKit class, that one is 10.5+, but my app, sigh, has to run under 10.4.